# Subset a 2 column data frame with unique rows, so that the values in each column are unique

Tags: r, dataframe, unique

I have a 2-column data frame with 1300 unique rows. The first column has 160 unique values and the second column has 230 unique values.
I would like to get a subset of the data frame with the maximum number of rows while keeping each column with unique values.

Here is a toy data frame where each row is a unique combination of values.

```
subject1 = c("A","B","C","D")
subject2 = c("0","1")
df = expand.grid(V1 = subject1, V2 = subject2)
df = df[-5,] #we delete a row so that the df does not have all possible combinations between subject1 and subject 2
  first second
   A    0
   B    0
   C    0
   D    0
   B    1
   C    1
   D    1
```

I would like to subset the data frame so that both columns only have unique values. The only condition is that it should have the maximum number of possible rows.

The desired output could be:

```
  V1   V2
   B    0
   C    1
```

or

```
  V1   V2
   D    1
   A    0
```

or any possible combination of unique values that appear on the original df.

It seems to me like a straightforward question, but I have not found any similar questions here,
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It could have been a case for a simple loop. It will, however, not guarantee you the maximum number of rows unless you order the dataset in all possible ways and run through them all ..

```r
df_new <- data.frame(V1 = character(0),
                     V2 = double(0))

for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  
  if((!df[i, "V1"] %in% df_new[, "V1"]) & (!df[i, "V2"] %in% df_new[, "V2"]))
    df_new <- rbind(df_new, df[i, ])
    
}
```

Output:

```
  V1 V2
1  A  0
6  B  1
```

Comment: That loop is helpful,  however as I need to find the maximum number of rows, and given that the original data frame has 1300 rows, the number of different row orders is close to 3 × 10^3495 so checking all combinations is not computationally feasible, at least on my computer.